# Ideals of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (i.e. the ring $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z} $), let $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k} $ where $p_i$'s are distinct primes. We know that if $ p_l < p_m $ then,

$$ | \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_r p_m \rangle | < | \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_r p_l \rangle |. $$

Now define a set
$$ \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_s \rangle ' = \{ x \in  \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_s \rangle \ \text{such that} \ \text{if} \ p_i\vert x \ \text{then} \ i= 1,2, \ldots s \} $$

then is it true ( if yes then how to show that ) if $ p_l < p_m $ then,

$$ | \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_r p_m \rangle '| < | \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_r p_l \rangle ' |. $$

where $ \langle y \rangle $ denotes the ideal generated by the element $y$ and $| . | $ denotes the cardinality of the set.

Basically $ \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_s \rangle ' $ is the set of the elements of the ideal $ \langle p_1p_2 \cdots p_s \rangle $ which are multiple of the primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots ,p_s $ only ( i.e. there is no other prime divisor of $n$ which divides the elements of this set).

I have tried to prove this by calculating the cardinality of that sets by the inclusion-exclusion formula but that is not working for this.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please add some context to your question and any preliminary work you may have done on this to give readers some idea of what you've tried.

Comment: I, for one, can't make heads or tails of the post.  If $\langle \cdot\rangle$ is meant to mean the ideal of $\mathbb Z$ generated by its contents, and $|\cdot|$ is meant to mean its cardinality of the contents, then no, the two things in the first display line have equal cardinality.  It *seems* like you might be wanting to look at the fact $(a)\subseteq (b)\iff b|a$, and what that means for $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.  Otherwise I'm not sure how you're going about things...

Comment: I guess you could be looking at the ideals generated in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, but it is not clear this is the case. I'm assuming $\mathbb Z_n$ means that ring, but some people will assume it means a different thing. Also a good thing to clarify. I'm also guessing you mean the $p_i$ are mutually distinct primes, too. (Are they?). if so, why are you investigating these products of single powers of these primes?  Adding my close vote to give you shelter to add to the question.